# Filter JSON array by value with Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, json

I have a JSON array that looks something like this.

```
[
 {"name":"Idaho","state":{"id":1,"name":"A"}},
 {"name":"Wyoming","state":{"id":1,"name":"A"}},
 {"name":"Montana","state":{"id":2,"name":"B"}},
 {"name":"South Dakota","state":{"id":1,"name":"B"}}
]
```

How would I use Ruby to only show the value of A?

I don't think sort_by will be the answer because what I have below just sorts them alphabetically. I want to completely exclude all results from B.

```
.sort_by { |a| [a.state.name] }
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this in a .rb file?

---

I solved my own question. This is how I achieved what I wanted.

```
.select { |a| a.state.name == "A" }
```

Comment: `a.state.name` is how you'd do it in JavaScript, but in Ruby this is `a['state']['name']`.

Comment: Also worth reading up on is the [`Enumerable#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) method.

Comment: Alternatively, `str.scan(/[A-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+(?=.+:\"A\".+?$)/) => ["Idaho", "Wyoming"]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require 'json'

json = <<'JSON_STRING'
[
 {"name":"Idaho","state":{"id":1,"name":"A"}},
 {"name":"Wyoming","state":{"id":1,"name":"A"}},
 {"name":"Montana","state":{"id":2,"name":"B"}},
 {"name":"South Dakota","state":{"id":1,"name":"B"}}
]
JSON_STRING

data = JSON.parse json

data.map(&:values).select { |state, values| values["name"] == ?A }
#=> [["Idaho", {"id"=>1, "name"=>"A"}], ["Wyoming", {"id"=>1, "name"=>"A"}]]

data.map(&:values).select { |state, values| values["name"] == ?A }.map(&:first)
#=> ["Idaho", "Wyoming"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'json'

arr = JSON.parse <<END_OF_JSON
[
 {"name":"Idaho","state":{"id":1,"name":"A"}},
 {"name":"Wyoming","state":{"id":1,"name":"A"}},
 {"name":"Montana","state":{"id":2,"name":"B"}},
 {"name":"South Dakota","state":{"id":1,"name":"B"}}
]
END_OF_JSON

results = []

arr.each do |hash|
  results << hash["name"] if hash["state"]["name"] == "A"
end

p results

--output:--
["Idaho", "Wyoming"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect:

```
.select { |a| a.state.name == "A" }
```

Correct way:

```
.select { |a| a['state']['name'] == 'A' }
```